# How to derive the differential equation of Q(t)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an euqation from a real physical system

$$Q(t)=\int_0^t{W(t)\over a+Q(t)} \mathrm dt -Ct,$$
where $a$ and $C$ are constants, $W(t)$ is a function.

I want to derive a diffential equation about $Q(t)$, can I write that

$${\mathrm d Q \over \mathrm dt} = {W(t)\over a+Q(t)}\cdot{-1\over Q(t)^2} -C .$$

Is this correct?

Edit:
$${\mathrm d Q \over \mathrm dt} = {W(t)\over a+Q(t)} -C .$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t \Longrightarrow F^{\prime}(x) = f(x)
\end{align*}